# Adobe AIR font embedding suddenly stopped working right

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I am completely stumped right now. I am working on an AIR application, everything was working perfectly, I did some small changes to code (completely unrelated to fonts, components or anything of this kind) when suddenly, during testing, I am flooded with hundreds of *warning: incompatible embedded font* errors. I didn't change any project settings, didn't make any framework update, I tried Clean and restating Flash Builder.

Now, I am working on a project which uses modules and both MX (only Datagrid) and Spark components, so I am using two versions of font:

```
@font-face {
  src:url("/assets/font/helvetica.otf");
  fontFamily: "Helvetica";
  embedAsCFF: true;
}
[...]
[Embed(source="../assets/font/helvetica_3.otf", fontFamily="Helvetica_2",
       embedAsCFF="false", mimeType="application/x-font")]
private var _font_:Class;
```

As you can guess, Helvetica is for Spark components while the other one is for MX. Two curious errors:

- `warning: incompatible embedded font 'Helvetica' specified for spark.components::Label (countdown) . This component requires that the embedded font be declared with embedAsCff=true` **Isn't it already?**
- `warning: incompatible embedded font 'Helvetica_2' specified for mx.controls.dataGridClasses::DataGridItemRenderer (DataGridItemRenderer501) . This component requires that the embedded font be declared with embedAsCff=false.` **Isn't it already too?!**

These errors relate to *MODULES* which I import into the project (yes, my own). Text in the main air app works more or less fine (Diacritic characters are not displayed anymore). I am using additionally these command line parameters:
`-isolate-styles=false` (So skins and ANYTHING is actually applied to the modules, without it there are no errors, but modules have no styles)
`-keep-all-type-selectors=true` (Removing this doesn't help anyway)

Anyone had similar problem and managed to find the cause? I tried to undo last changes I made but without avail...

### Update:

Well, weird enough I found the source of problem. In one of the module's components I imported class which is also imported by Main app, which resulted in problem. The funny thing is, it worked fine until I cloned the component to make a similar one, which isn't even imported to ANY of the modules yet. Once again Flex proved it's weirdness.